# What does "Never use a proprietary cipher" mean?

Tags: cryptography

I'm taking cryptography course on cousera.
When I'm reading the lecture slides, it says

---

Encryption algorithm is publicly known

### • Never use a proprietary cipher

What does "Never use a proprietary cipher" mean?

Thanks

Comment: It means don't use a cipher that is proprietary. As the material you've posted clarifies, that means don't use a cipher whose encryption algorithm isn't publicly known. Was there a specific part of that that was unclear?

Comment: ["Proprietary items usually have distinctive characteristics or features, and are often incompatible with competing items."](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/proprietary.html) - also, they may be less robust (eg. receive less attention devoted by many people over time) and/or rely on 'security by obscurity'.There are only very "specific" use-cases (eg. interoperability outside of control) to use something other than a still-secure well-published/understood public cipher.

Comment: This seems more like an English language question than a Software Development question. The sentence means exactly what it means, there is no secret meaning, no hidden jargon, no technical terms in it. It's just an ordinary English sentence using ordinary English words with their ordinary English meaning.

Comment: I think my question is not clear. My question should be What's the reason not using proprietary cipher?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) without involving programming. @user2238736 You should edit the question instead of adjusting it in the comments.

Comment: While I agree w/ Maarten Bodewes that this question would be better for crypto.stackexchange.com, the general gist is that without widespread scrutiny from multiple disciplines, one cannot know that a cipher is secure.  Proprietary ciphers tend to limit such scrutiny (either through licensing restrictions, NDAs, just by keeping them as trade-secrets, etc.)  Per the second of [Kerckhoffs's principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) a cipher should remain secure even if its algorithm is publicly known; so people worry about why a closed-source cipher is kept secret.

Answer (score 2):

> Never use a proprietary cipher

It means - **Never use a proprietary cipher**!

The idea behind is - until a cipher is adopted as a standard, the cipher goes through mathematical elaboration, proofs, validation, ... and then a lot of smart people say it's ok to use the cipher to some extends or expected lifetime.

Almost all current battle-proven ciphers went this way (AES, RC4, DES, 3DES, ...). We know (or we think we know) their real strength and their weaknesses.

When creating a proprietary cipher - everybody could create a cipher which himself won't be able to break. However - are you able to validate, if the cipher is resistant to modern cryptoanalytical methods or side-channel attacks?

Using a cipher which is "proprietary", where the algorithm is not know, most probably the cipher can be broken and the cipher is not to be considered as secure. Stick to the industrial standards.

Answer (score 0):

Proprietary ciphers go through much less rigorous testing than public ciphers do